# heat map and balance average

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I have a data frame `abc`.
How can I make a heat map so we can see average balance changed on each account during the years, and write at least 3 observations from the heatmap?

```
>abc
     time        account_a    account_b      account_c
    1  2018-01-01  2919.446     7774.078       1042.3338
    2  2018-02-01  2649.327     7810.399       436.1774
```

The heatmap should look like this:

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in two steps:

1. Transform data to 'long' format with one column for balance and one for account name. You can use `tidyr::gather` for this.
2. Generate the plot with `ggplot` and `geom_tile`

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

abc %>%
  gather(account, balance, c(account_a, account_b, account_c)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, account, fill = balance)) +
  geom_tile()
```

Comment: Thanks kwiscion! Maybe you can give me good suggestion for good R programming courses or books? :)

Comment: There is a great book "R for Data Science" and it's available online: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/